# Error: Shuffle needs to be initialized with an element

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, shuffle

I have this code but console is giving me an error is giving me an error "Shuffle needs to be initialized with an element". This is html

```
<div class="gallery-grid">
                <div class="gallery-item" data-date-created="2016-08-12">1</div>
                <div class="gallery-item" data-date-created="2016-08-13">2</div>
                <div class="gallery-item" data-date-created="2016-08-14">3</div>
                <div class="gallery-item" data-date-created="2016-08-15">4</div>
                <div class="gallery-item" data-date-created="2016-08-16">5</div>
                <div class="gallery-item" data-date-created="2016-08-17">6</div>
                <div class="gallery-item" data-date-created="2016-08-18">7</div>
                <div class="gallery-item" data-date-created="2016-08-19">8</div>
                <div class="gallery-item" data-date-created="2016-08-20">9</div>
                <div class="gallery-item" data-date-created="2016-08-21">10</div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
const shuffleInstance = new Shuffle(document.getElementsByClassName('gallery-grid'), {
          itemSelector: '.gallery-item',
          sizer: '.gallery-item',
          speed: 500,
          easing: 'ease-out'
      });

      shuffleInstance.Shuffle();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array like object of all elements with the given class, so you need to specify which item in the array you want, if you want the first found instance of gallery-grid then use:

`document.getElementsByClassName('gallery-grid')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The solution of linasmnew didn't work for me. So for anyone else interested: Javascript sometimes is initialzied before the HTML document is loaded(and there is no element to load yet) and so you have to include

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//code here
}
```

or without using jquery:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
//code here
});
```